# CentOS - Cannot install because there is no space on disk

Tags: hard-drive, centos-7

I want to install CentOS and I already have Windows 10 installed.
So I made some space

[image: Windows Disk Manager]

As you can see on picture there is free space and the disk is basic not Windows Dynamic.

And now when I go to the installation menu I can see there that there is free space on disk (CentOS says it), but I cannot choose it. In fact all I can do is delete my D: disk, not resize only delete. If I just click Ok on everything it says that it cannot get information about the disk. I have selected Automatically configure partitions

How can I solve it?

This is the step I froze on (not my image from my installation)

[image: Step]

So I went back on the installation and I finally got some error message when I clicked on I will configure partition, than I pressed Configure automatically.

[image: Edit2-Error]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/998024/filip-barto%c5%a1 and https://superuser.com/users/998037/filip-barto%c5%a1. You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, if you try to edit your own post without logging in to the account, the edit shows up as an attempted anonymous edit in a review queue.  The proposed edit looks like it must be you.

Answer (score 1):

The free space on the disk you are talking about has no partition on it. The best way to continue is using gparted via a live-cd linux boot. That will allow you to resize and create the partitions where windows won't allow you to. If you can install something like an ubuntu live-cd on a usb and boot to that, that'll be the easiest way to continue.

A screenshot/screen photo of the install on your machine would be really helpful to diagnose further.

Regarding the error you have, this is because you are trying to install to a partition without a boot section/MBR, which is on your second (C:) disk. To get around this, you'll have to select the second disk to install GRUB or another bootloader to. Otherwise, install it to the first disk, but you'll have to select the startup disk via the bios when you boot.

A reminder to make sure you have a backup before attempting any disk operations.

If you can't use a livecd to create the partition, try clicking "I will configure partitioning" after selecting the D disk. Nothing will be erased at this stage.

Then create 2 partitions in the remaining space on the D disk. One will be the main partition for `/` and `/boot`, and one should be the swap partition (with size == the amount of ram you have, as a rule of thumb).

After that you should be able to proceed as per usual.

Comment: I’m very confused. I’m not saying that you’re wrong, since the OP says that you’re right, but how can the disk not be formatted? [The OP’s image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JAC1.png) seems to me to clearly show partitions.

Comment: My mistake, I meant the partition. Updated to reflect